# Watson Speech to Text request to German servers

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text

I am trying to use the IBM Bluemix German STT servers. Within the Bluemix environment, the (english) documentation has a different link as the (german) link that is shown next to my authentication credentials. Not suprisiningly, the method described by the documentation tells me I don't have access rights. Using that method on the German URL tells me I am not using the right request method. So, anybody any idea how I can get the german servers to return my transcription of the audio file?

PS. This link is in the right direction, but the explanation for the SST questions is for the TTS service:
[How can I access IBM speech-to-text api with curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39936567/how-can-i-access-ibm-speech-to-text-api-with-curl)
PS2. I need the German servers as data should not leave the country

US/global servers

```
curl -X POST -u {username}:{password} --header "Content-Type: audio/flac" --header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" --data-binary ./audio-file.flac "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize"
```

returns

```
{ "code" : 401 , "error" : "Not Authorized" , "description" : "2017-07-21T05:15:17-04:00, Error ERCDPLTFRM-DNLKUPERR occurred when accessing https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize, Tran-Id: stream-dp02-872773132 - Invalid UserId and/or Password. Please confirm that your credentials match the end-point you are trying to access. A common error is trying to use credentials from an experimental or beta release against a GA release or vice versa" }
```

German servers

```
curl -X POST -u {username}:{password}--header "Content-Type: audio/flac" --header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" --data-binary ./audio-file.flac "https://stream-fra.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api"
```

response

```
    {
  "error": "Your browser approached me (at /speech-to-text/api) with the method \"POST\".  I only allow the methods HEAD, GET here.",
  "code": 405,
  "code_description": "Method Not Allowed"
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/#recognize_sessions_nonmp18 for the syntax and options? You need to adapt that shown URI to the Frankfurt server.

Comment: Ruling out the obvious. Are you supplying your service username and password? Also the service credentials should give you the end point URL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks data_henrik for providing me with the correct suggestion. Please feel free to write your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer:
Instead of

```
curl -X POST -u {username}:{password}--header "Content-Type: audio/flac" --header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" --data-binary ./audio-file.flac "https://stream-fra.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api"
```

I should have used

```
curl -X POST -u {username}:{password} --header "Content-Type: audio/flac" --data-binary "@audio-file.flac" "https://stream-fra.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize"
```

Difference: the v1/recognize at the end of the link.